# Implementation of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck noise in DDPG

Tags: numpy, reinforcement-learning

I am confused about the implementation of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck noise in DDPG framework. I understand the equation of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process but I am not sure how should I actually use it in the DDPG algorithm. The OU noise in code is simply

```
dx = theta * (mu - x) * dt + sigma * np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.normal(size=action_dim)
x = x + dx
```

But, where I am confused about is the way of adding the noise. For each time step, should the $x$ be set as the actor-network output, or do I need to give a $x_0$ independent to the actor-network output at the beginning of the trajectory?

```
give an x0 at the beginning of the trajectory
dx = theta * (mu - x0) * dt + sigma * np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.normal(size=action_dim)
x0 = x0 + dx
return x0 as noise
```

or

```
at = actor(st)
dx = theta * (mu - at) * dt + sigma * np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.normal(size=action_dim)
noise = at + dx
```